# Lebesgue integral $f(x)= \int_{(0,1)} \frac {1}{1-x^3}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, power-series, lebesgue-integral

I am studying about power series on topic Series of Functions and i am trying to solve some exercise. I see [exapmle 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872305/express-arctan2x-as-power-series?rq=1) to solve my problem. Here the question :

Express the Lebesgue integral $$F(x)= \int_{(0,1)} \frac {1}{1-x^3}dx$$ as a power series.

My attempt :

From the function $f(x)=\frac1{1-x^3}$, I got the power series representation  $f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (x^3)^n$.

Then what is the next step ?

Comment: Change the order of integration and summation (with care).

Comment: I changed your notation since you used $f$ double. Be careful not to use a name for different functions in one context.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Unfortunately, the modified identity $$F(x)= \int_{(0,1)} \frac {1}{1-x^3}dx$$ is as absurd as the preceding one since the RHS does not depend on $x$.

Comment: @Did: Oh I see... I just changed the names and not the meaning. Lin wrote $f(x)=\int_{(0,1)}\frac1{1-x^3}dx$ which has the same problem. Hence Lin should reedit it.

Answer (score 1):

$f_m = \sum_{n=0}^{m} x^{3n} $ is a sequence of monotone measurable functions on $[0,1]$ which converge to $\frac{1}{1-x^3}$  The monotone convergence theorem allows for

$$\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{3n}dx = \int_{0}^{1} \lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{m} x^{3n}dx = \lim_{m \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{m} x^{3n}  dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3n+1} $$

Comment: And both sides are $$\color{red}{+\infty}$$